# how can I connect to a remote machine like ssh

Tags: ssh, cloud, gpu, cpu, rtx

I want to make an rtx rental website So that anyone who owns an rtx rents it to me and I pay him for it.

But how can I connect to a remote machine like ssh
So that the connection is to use only the graphics card
And I can't check out the files
The connection should be for graphics card use only.

I want to make an rtx rental website So that anyone who owns an rtx rents it to me and I pay him for it.

But how can I connect to a remote machine like SSH
so that the connection is to use only the graphics card
and I can't check out the files. The connection should be for graphics card use only.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can do it. Whatever you want to do, you might want to look into cloud computing - it's a similar thing, but a company is renting you processing power (either GPU or CPU)